# Flutter: Converting map api data to list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform

When I make a fetch request, the received data is of map type, but I need to be able to convert it to list type, how can I do it?

When I make a fetch request, the received data is of map type, but I need to be able to convert it to list type, how can I do it?

```
Future<AltinModel> altinGetir() async {
    String url = 'https://finans.truncgil.com/v2/today.json';
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('error');
   }

   var altin = utf8.decode(res.body.runes.toList());
   var js = json.decode(altin);
   var gram_altin = json.decode(res.body);

  return AltinModel.fromJson(js);

 }
```

model class
model class
model class
model class

```
  // To parse this JSON data, do
  //
  //     final altinModel = altinModelFromJson(jsonString);

  import 'dart:convert';

  AltinModel altinModelFromJson(String str) =>
       AltinModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String altinModelToJson(AltinModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class AltinModel {
   AltinModel({
    required this.updateDate,
    required this.onsAltin,
    required this.gramAltin,
    required this.ceyrekAltin,
    required this.yarimAltin,
    required this.tamAltin,
    required this.cumhuriyetAltini,
    required this.ataAltin,
    required this.resatAltin,
    required this.hamitAltin,
    required this.ikibucukAltin,
    required this.gremseAltin,
    required this.besliAltin,
    required this.the14AyarAltin,
    required this.the18AyarAltin,
    required this.the22AyarBilezik,
    required this.gumus,
    });

  DateTime updateDate;
  The14AyarAltin onsAltin;
  The14AyarAltin gramAltin;
  The14AyarAltin ceyrekAltin;
  The14AyarAltin yarimAltin;
  The14AyarAltin tamAltin;
  The14AyarAltin cumhuriyetAltini;
  The14AyarAltin ataAltin;
  The14AyarAltin resatAltin;
  The14AyarAltin hamitAltin;
  The14AyarAltin ikibucukAltin;
  The14AyarAltin gremseAltin;
  The14AyarAltin besliAltin;
  The14AyarAltin the14AyarAltin;
  The14AyarAltin the18AyarAltin;
  The14AyarAltin the22AyarBilezik;
  The14AyarAltin gumus;

    factory AltinModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AltinModel(
      updateDate: DateTime.parse(json["Update_Date"]),
      onsAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["ons_altin"]),
      gramAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["gram_altin"]),
      ceyrekAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["ceyrek_altin"]),
      yarimAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["yarim_altin"]),
      tamAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["tam_altin"]),
      cumhuriyetAltini: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["cumhuriyet_altini"]),
      ataAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["ata_altin"]),
      resatAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["resat_altin"]),
      hamitAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["hamit_altin"]),
      ikibucukAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["ikibucuk_altin"]),
      gremseAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["gremse_altin"]),
      besliAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["besli_altin"]),
      the14AyarAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["14_ayar_altin"]),
      the18AyarAltin: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["18_ayar_altin"]),
      the22AyarBilezik: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["22_ayar_bilezik"]),
      gumus: The14AyarAltin.fromJson(json["gumus"]),
    );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Update_Date": updateDate.toIso8601String(),
    "ons_altin": onsAltin.toJson(),
    "gram_altin": gramAltin.toJson(),
    "ceyrek_altin": ceyrekAltin.toJson(),
    "yarim_altin": yarimAltin.toJson(),
    "tam_altin": tamAltin.toJson(),
    "cumhuriyet_altini": cumhuriyetAltini.toJson(),
    "ata_altin": ataAltin.toJson(),
    "resat_altin": resatAltin.toJson(),
    "hamit_altin": hamitAltin.toJson(),
    "ikibucuk_altin": ikibucukAltin.toJson(),
    "gremse_altin": gremseAltin.toJson(),
    "besli_altin": besliAltin.toJson(),
    "14_ayar_altin": the14AyarAltin.toJson(),
    "18_ayar_altin": the18AyarAltin.toJson(),
    "22_ayar_bilezik": the22AyarBilezik.toJson(),
    "gumus": gumus.toJson(),
      };
   }

  class The14AyarAltin {
    The14AyarAltin({
     required this.buying,
     required this.selling,
     required this.type,
     required this.name,
   });

 String buying;
 String selling;
 String type;
 String name;

factory The14AyarAltin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => The14AyarAltin(
    buying: json["Buying"],
    selling: json["Selling"],
    type: json["Type"],
    name: json["Name"],
   );



Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "Buying": buying,
      "Selling": selling,
      "Type": type,
      "Name": name,
     };


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT3 : After testing your code, i see now what you are trying to do.

Here is my answer to your problem, please feel free to comment if you don't like it.

For my own comprehension, i changed some names here.

The14AyarAlin become my model class :

```
import 'package:stackoverflow/helper.dart' as helper;

class Altin {
  Altin({
    required this.key,
    required this.buying,
    required this.selling,
    required this.type,
    required this.name,
  });

  String key;
  double buying;
  double selling;
  String type;
  String name;

  factory Altin.fromJson(String key, Map<String, dynamic> map) => Altin(
    key : key,
    buying: helper.stringToDouble(map["Buying"]),
    selling: helper.stringToDouble(map["Selling"]),
    type: map["Type"],
    name: map["Name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Buying": helper.doubleToString(buying),
    "Selling": helper.doubleToString(selling),
    "Type": type,
    "Name": name,
  };
}
```

and your AltinModel became AyarAtlins :

```
import 'package:stackoverflow/models/altin.dart';

class AyarAltins {
  AyarAltins({
    required this.updateDate,
    required this.elements,
  });

  final DateTime updateDate;
  final List<Altin> elements;

  factory AyarAltins.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    DateTime updateDate = DateTime.parse(json["Update_Date"]);
    List<Altin> elements = [];

    json.remove('Update_Date');
    json.forEach((key, value) {
      elements.add(Altin.fromJson(key, value));
    });

    return AyarAltins(
        updateDate: updateDate,
        elements: elements
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "Update_Date": updateDate.toIso8601String()
    };

    for (var element in elements) {
      map[element.key] = element.toJson();
    }

    return map;
  }
}
```

i tested it with

```
Future getData() async {
  AyarAltins ayarAltins = await altinGetir();

  Map<String, dynamic> map = ayarAltins.toJson();

  print('end');
}

Future<AyarAltins> altinGetir() async {
  String url = 'https://finans.truncgil.com/v2/today.json';
  final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  if (res.statusCode != 200) {
    throw Exception('error');
  }

  var altin = utf8.decode(res.body.runes.toList());
  var js = json.decode(altin);

  return AyarAltins.fromJson(js);

}
```

and everything seems ok here.

I change some value from string to double for better handling. To do that i use a file named helper.

```
double stringToDouble(String text) {
  text = text.replaceAll('.', '');
  text = text.replaceAll(',', '.');
  return double.parse(text);
}

String doubleToString(double value) {
  String text = value.toString();

  if(text.contains('.')) {
    List<String> split = text.split('.');

    text = '${_comaFormat(split[0])}.${split[1]}';
  } else {
    text = _comaFormat(text);
  }
  
  return text;
}

String _comaFormat(String text){
  String formatted = "";
  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = (text.length - 1);  i >= 0; i--){
    counter++;
    String str = text[i];
    if((counter % 3) != 0 && i !=0){
      formatted = "$str$formatted";
    }else if(i == 0 ){
      formatted = "$str$formatted";

    }else{
      formatted = ",$str$formatted";
    }
  }
  return formatted.trim();
}
```

To extract list from your new AyarAltins you can use now for example:

```
List<Altin> filteredList = ayarAltins.elements.where((element) => element.buying > 700).toList();
```

Here it will return a list of 11 elements with buying value > 700.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works great.
but I didn't fully understand the working logic, I think I need to find a shorter solution

Comment: it will be hard to be shorter.. you have dynamic creation , casting into double, capacity of filtering. If you are satisfied with the anwser thought, can you accepted my response to solution to the question? 

Ill try to explain the logic : 
you create a data model. You assign this data model to your class which handles the data input dynamically. 
Whether you have 16 data or 10k data doesn't change anything (except the process time).

I convert the string to a double to be able to manipulate it more easily, the data being a number. That's all.